My chromebook died...cant afford to replace...do I have to buy another chromebook to be able to get the passwords that were saved?
I cannot change my passwords without knowing the old passwords, effectively locking me out of all my accounts. Is there a fix you can advise me of? thanks for any advice.

I'm not 100% sure, but knowing google, I would bet that everything is stored in your google account anyway.

Contact Google? They're as likely to help as always!

If you use another device to login at passwords.google.com does it list your saved passwords from Chromebook?

@RedGrittyBrick your suggestion worked. My passwords were there. Thank you more than you know for your assistance. I'm grateful.

If you use another device to login at passwords.google.com it should list your saved passwords from Chromebook
